# Looking To Create Password Protected Git Repository

Tags: git

I've been doing Project Euler solutions and would like to put them in a git repository that I can then link to on my resume. However, I understand that it is frowned upon to publish the solutions.

I thought I might get around this by setting up a git repository that anyone can access as long as they have the password (which will only be listed on my resume). That would allow anyone who wants to see my solutions as a potential employer to see them, but would keep out anyone casually Googling solutions.

Github and Bitbucket don't seem to have an option for this, and my search hasn't turned up anything that does. I've thought about making a password-protected Wiki and linking to that from a readme document in Github, but that's a little clunky since it involves a potential employer hopping through multiple links.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you can set up your own git server (using your favorite vps or cloud hosting provider, for example) this would be easy (because git access is via either ssh or http, and password authentication is easy and common for both mechanisms).

Comment: Gitlab allows free private repositories. Only people you invite into the repo can see it. Bitbucket and Github also offer this, but it's a subscription-only feature on those sites.

Answer (score -1):

You could obfuscate the important files in the otherwise public git repositories. Simply XOR them with some password which you then share with your potential employers (provide a little script along with your source which does the encoding/decoding; be sure to have scripts for Windows and Unix, the Windows version probably being the more important one).

The benefit over outright encryption would be (aside from not requiring your employer to have your encryption tool at hand) that if you change your files later and commit again, the usual operations (merge, diff, blame etc.) will still work fine. Sure, diff/blame will only output gibberish, but at least in the correct lines.